# Qt Signal with custom type

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to send a signal with Qt with a parameter. This parameter should be a self defined struct. I already register it with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE, but it doesn't work, I get some strange compile errors.

Her is my code:

helper.h

```
#ifndef HELPER_H
#define HELPER_H

#include <QString>
#include <QMetaType>
struct result{
    QString info;
bool sugestion;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(result)

#endif // HELPER_H
```

analyser.h

```
#ifndef ANALYSER_H
#define ANALYSER_H
#include "helper.h"
#include <QObject>

class analyser: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void test()
    {
        result ret;
        ret.info="Hallo";
        emit show(ret);
    }
signals:
    void show(result r);
};

#endif // ANALYSER_H
```

qmlbackend.h

```
#ifndef QMLBACKEND_H
#define QMLBACKEND_H

#include <QObject>
#include "helper.h"
#include <QDebug>

class QmlBackend : public QObject
{
public slots:
    void hit(result res)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Working"<<res.info;
    }
 };

 #endif // QMLBACKEND_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QDebug>
#include "qmlbackend.h"
#include "analyser.h"
#include <QGuiApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QmlBackend b;
    analyser t;
    QObject::connect(&t,&analyser::show,&b,&QmlBackend::hit);
    t.test();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Compiler output:

```
moc_analyser.cpp: In static member function 'static void analyser::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)':
moc_analyser.cpp:91:49: error: cannot declare pointer to 'void' member
         typedef void (analyser::*_t)(result );
                                             ^
moc_analyser.cpp:91:49: error: typedef '_t' is initialized (use decltype instead)
moc_analyser.cpp:92:35: error: '_t' does not name a type; did you mean '_o'?
         if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(func) == static_cast<_t>(&analyser::show)) {
                               ^~
moc_analyser.cpp:92:38: error: expected '>' before '*' token
         if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(func) == static_cast<_t>(&analyser::show)) {
                                  ^
moc_analyser.cpp:92:38: error: expected '(' before '*' token
moc_analyser.cpp:92:39: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
         if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(func) == static_cast<_t>(&analyser::show)) {
                                   ^
moc_analyser.cpp:92:62: error: '_t' does not name a type; did you mean '_o'?
         if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(func) == static_cast<_t>(&analyser::show)) {
                                                          ^~
                                                          _o
moc_analyser.cpp:92:84: error: expected ')' before '{' token
         if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(func) == static_cast<_t>(&analyser::show)) {
                                                                                ^
moc_analyser.cpp:96:9: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
     }
     ^
```

Can anybody tell me why it doesn't work or what I have to change?

Comment: No I don't do that, but you remember me that I should write that it's a compile time problem. So registering my type this way wouldn't help, or?

Comment: Registering will not help with a compiler error. Sorry. I don't use qml.

Comment: It is a bit strange, proving your code generates the same error but if I change the structure name of `result` to `Result` compiles correctly (I recommend you delete the build folder)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little strange, proving your code generates the same error but if I change the structure name of `result` to `Result` compiles and executes correctly (I recommend you delete the build folder and then compile).

I am looking for Qt documentation where it indicates that the data type should be capitalized when using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`.

Comment: Yeah, the same applies e.g. to `Q_ENUM`, the values MUST have the first letter capital to correctly work. It' a general strict rule due to some implementation detail. But it's really not a big deal since by naming convention both classes/structure/enums have - at least - first letter capitalised. You should make the statement more prominent in your answer.  :)

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo In what part of Qt's documentation does that convention indicate? because that's not part of the C ++ standard. :P

Comment: For the enums look [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html#using-enumerations-of-a-custom-type). I guess the same applies to types, at least this example shows that. Honestly - **by coding conventions** :D - I've always wrote my types with the first letter uppercase so I do not have a direct experience with registered type which has a lowercase first letter! Maybe I'm wrong for types, but it's surely the case for enums.

Comment: I also use the convention, but that indication is not explicit since the same is shown in the example of how to register struct.

Comment: Where the example? I've miss it. Well, if it's like that my apologies. As I said it was an assumption. :) I still think the rule must be made prominent for ENUMs because I saw SO MANY questions missing that point, even recently. Capital case it's the new `clip:true` for QML. :D

Comment: Yes, in the documentation examples use capitalized words to name enumerations, structures, etc. To see the example of how to register struct see the following link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE :P

Comment: Oh no, ok. I thought you were saying there was a NON capitalised example! That's ok, I knew the capitalised ones! :D But now I'm curious about the non-capitalised scenario. Ah well, I'm coding other stuff this morning.